# one-to-many vs store ids in one record

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

There are two tables: questions and courses
One course will have many questions, one-to-many.

For each user who uses our web application, he/she will be allowed to save e.g. 30 courses in our server.
One way is to setup an one-to-many relationship.
The other is to combine all question id to generate a json string and store it in a course record. this way it is easier to manager quota for user I think. But how to get all questions of one course from the database by their IDs efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using a relational database then you should follow well established relational database concepts. In this case you should properly implement the one-to-many relationship that you say exists. The json string will cause you nothing but problems in the long run.

Comment: for one-to-many, not easy to set quota for each user.